# sails.js Logic error in mySQL ORM error catching

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

In my user model I have:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        username: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true,
            required: true,
            minLength: 5,
            maxLength: 15,          
            alphanumeric: true
        }
      }
}
```

Now when I try and insert a duplicate username I get the following message:

> Logic error in mySQL ORM.
>
> { [Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'username' for key 'username']
>   code: 'ER
>   _DUP_ENTRY', index: 0 }

Now my question is how do I catch this error so I can display a custom error message to the user? My create is like so:

```
User.create({
    username: "username"
}).done(function(err, data){
    if(err){
               //the error isn't here
    }
});
```

Comment: `done` is deprecated, as its usage was confusing (since there's often a `done` in promise libraries).  Use `exec` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the done callback, but you can try using the promise `then` handlers

```
User.create({
    username: "username"
})
.then(function(data){
    console.log("Success", data);
},function(err){
    console.log("My error here", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.create({
    username: "username"
}).exec(function(err, data){
    if(err){
           //the error isn't here
    }
    // data process
});
```